# how does kafka consumer iterator work

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka

I have found this code which successfully reads kafka topic and prints each  messages on the screen. I would like to extend it to perform other operation on the string instead of just printing on the screen. For this I would like to understand what is happening in the while loop which iterates the messages. what does it.hasNext() do? does it look for next message or list of new messages. When will it get out of this while loop?

```
import kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator;
import kafka.consumer.KafkaStream;

public class ConsumerTest implements Runnable {
    private KafkaStream m_stream;
    private int m_threadNumber;

    public ConsumerTest(KafkaStream a_stream, int a_threadNumber) {
        m_threadNumber = a_threadNumber;
        m_stream = a_stream;
    }

    public void run() {
        **ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = m_stream.iterator();
          while (it.hasNext())**
            System.out.println("Thread " + m_threadNumber + ": " + new String(it.next().message()));
           System.out.println("Shutting down Thread: " + m_threadNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: where did you find this ? I found this here https://github.com/bkimminich/apache-kafka-book-examples/tree/master/src/test/kafka/consumer but it has no consumerIterator.

Answer (score 2):

Kafka iterator .hasNext() method normally always return true ! So you'll never get outside of the loop in standard operations. However, if an exception occur, it may return false and stop the fetching.

So, in general, you'll get in the loop, and the call to it.next() is actually blocking until there's a message to consume, in which case it will be returned.

Comment: What happens when hasNext is blocked an kafka brokers goes down. Does hasNext throw any exception or simply return false.

Comment: I'm really not sure. I don't think it would ever return false in fact, but it may either stay blocked, either throw I guess ? You'll need to simulate the case to have a reliable answer though ^^

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is an old question and kafka 0.8 is probably rarely used in production and kafka 0.10 offers a richer API, I'd like to add that the ConsumerIterator's method `hasNext()` is a blocking operation waiting for messages.

So if you for example want to use the consumer to read all the data that has been sent earlier and return when finished you could set the property `"consumer.timeout.ms"` to e.g. `100` resulting in `hasNext()` throwing a `ConsumerTimeoutException` when blocking longer than timeout.

In your code just catch the exception in the while loop:

```
try {
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String message = new String(it.next().message()));
        // do sth with message
    }
} catch {
    case t: ConsumerTimeoutException => // empty
} finally {
    // close your consumer
}
```